# Support of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, matroids

What is the support of a signed vector? By signed vector, I mean a vector which is determined by considering the signs of the coefficients of the entries of another vector.

Comment: What do you mean by support?  Can you give an example?

Comment: support of a vector is the number of non-zero elements in that vector.

Comment: Why don't you post that as an answer? @TenaliRaman

Comment: related: [ℓ0 Minimization (Minimizing the support of a vector)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170162/ell-0-minimization-minimizing-the-support-of-a-vector)

Comment: The wikipedia page for support functions is a good place to start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)

Answer (score 5):

According to TenaliRaman, "support of a vector is the number of non-zero elements in that vector."

I posted it here for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be an $n$-dimensional sign vector, i.e., a vector in $\{+,-,0\}^n$. The following is a natural partition of $[n]$ induced by $\mathbf{v}$.

- $\mathbf{v}^+ = \{i \in [n] | v_i = +\}$
- $\mathbf{v}^- = \{i \in [n] | v_i = -\}$
- $\mathbf{v}^0 = \{i \in [n] | v_i = 0\}$

The **support** of $\mathbf{v}$ is the *set* $[n] \setminus \mathbf{v}^0 = \mathbf{v}^+ \cup \mathbf{v}^-$ consisting of all indices corresponding to nonzero entries in $\mathbf{v}$.

See page 8 of [Oriented Matroids](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1bc3/1416236941d6341e1cfce0b2e297cd5b3c67.pdf) for the above definition and the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) for more generality.